# Does this sentence use acceptable English?

Tags: word-choice

Today our class had a listening comprehension in which there was a statement that read

> It's very surprisingly that the British could control such a big
>   country as India.

To me, this sounds wrong. I would write this statement like this "It's very surprising that the British could control a country as big as India". Is the original sentence grammatical English? Is my sentence proper English?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your sentence. However, there is also nothing wrong with the sentence your teacher wrote except that *surprisingly* should read *surprising*.

Comment: "such a <adjective> <noun> as" is a common set phrase.  You will see "such a famous actor as", "such an important politician as", "such a notorious criminal as", "such a big building as", etc.

Comment: In British English  

> It's surprising that the British could control as big a country as India

would seem more idiomatic. Better still would be to replace 'big' with 'large'. However as WS2 says the only thing that is actually wrong is the use of 'surprisingly' instead of 'surprising'

Comment: Your variant is fine. And so is the first, except that adverbial "surprisingly" is wrong - it should be adjectival "surprising". Incidentally, this kind of construction is called "extraposition".

Comment: "Surprisingly" is wrong, and, aside from that, the sentence is quite a bit more awkward than your replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's very surprising that the British could control such as big  country as India

implies that it is surprising that the British could control India. Why is it surprising? Because India is so big.

> It's very surprising that the British could control a country as big as India

implies that it is surprising that the British could control a large country. How large? The same size as India.  The second does not actually imply that the British controlled India, merely that they controlled a country of that size.

Manchester has no underground trains. Glasgow, a city of roughly the same size, does have underground trains.

We might say

> It is very surprising that such a big city as Manchester has no underground trains.

but we might also say, especially if speaking to someone who knew the size of Glasgow, but did not know Manchester

> It is very surprising that a city as big as Glasgow has no underground trains.

In this example "a city as big as Glasgow" does not refer to Glasgow, but to a city as big as Glasgow, in this case Manchester.

Therefore, since your teacher  was saying that it is surprising the British controlled India (surprising because of its size) I think his version is more correct in the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher said sounds somewhat unusual to me, and if you bear with me there's a logical reason why.

First off, I should point out that "Surprisingly" is wrong this in this sentence. You need an adjective not an adverb.

Now, getting to the issue at hand, I would say:

> "It's very surprising that the British could control as big a country as India."

Alternatively

> "It's very surprising that the British could control a country as big as India."

also sounds like a perfectly natural sentence. The syntax of both sentences is valid.

> "such a big country as India."

doesn't sound very natural to me.

"such" is classed as a determiner. However, sometimes it functions as a kind of demonstrative pronoun. To demonstrate:

> "India is very large. It's surprising that the British could control such a big country"

This means more or less the same as:

> "India is very large. It's surprising that the British control a country as big as **that one**."

In the above sentence "such" acts as a stand in that refers to India, it tells us the size of country we're talking about is the size of India. Now "such" doesn't always function in this way, but in the sentence above it does. Compare this with.

> "India is such a big country"

In this sentence "such" merely functions as an intensifier. The sentence only means something like

> "India is a really big country".

Anyway to get to the bottom of this, using "such" in the way your teacher has, while using "as India" to specify precisely which country size he's referring to, feels unnatural. This is because it would typically appear in a sentence like this one playing a demonstrative role, and there's no need for a demonstrative when you are referring directly to what the demonstrative would stand in for (in this case "India"). Unless you're just using it as an intensifier, "such" needs something to stand in for, but having a stand in within your sentence becomes unnecessary when you mention it by name.

Many people have said it's not an incorrect use of "such" though. I'd be inclined to agree, it's not strictly incorrect, but isn't a construction a native speaker would frequently use due to the redundancy of using "such" in this context.

Comment: Could you use some formatting such as > blockquotes for example sentences to make your answer look better?